# group by day when column is in unixtimestamp

Tags: sqlite

I have a table that has time in unixtimestamp (ms), I want to convert time only to day and group by day with aggregated function COUNT. I tried this but it didnt work:

```
SELECT
strftime('%d',(timestamp+1465876799998)/1000, 'unixepoch') a
COUNT(strftime('%d',(timestamp+1465876799998)/1000, 'unixepoch'))
FROM
clicks_train_
GROUP BY
strftime('%d',(timestamp+1465876799998)/1000, 'unixepoch')
ORDER BY strftime('%d',(timestamp+1465876799998)/1000, 'unixepoch') DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: `but it didnt work` ... what didn't work?  Did it not give you the expected results or did you get an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `strftime` with a format specifier to the day:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d', timestamp / 1000, 'unixepoch'),
       COUNT(*)
FROM clicks_train_
GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d', timestamp / 1000, 'unixepoch')
ORDER BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d', timestamp / 1000, 'unixepoch') DESC
LIMIT 10;
```